# What exactly did the cURL @-syntax do?

Tags: php, curl

I know that it's deprecated by now, but I got a hold of a library that uses the @-syntax to post a file through cURL. I have a bit of a twist, though; I'm actually constructing the file contents inline, and I think it'd be a bit overkill to save it to a file to push it over.

So my question is: what does the syntax exactly do? Does it open the file, encode it in some way and post the contents through? And can I handle that inline?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Best Regards,
Rasmus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per the curl man pages `-`  reads data from `stdin` when used with `@`, so for example

`echo "hello" | curl -v 'http://localhost:5000' -F "test=@-"`  posts "hello" to the url mentioned.

So if you pipe your contents that you construct inline I think it should work.